# A graph $G$ where $d(u)+d(v) \geq n-1$ for all vertices must be connected

Tags: graph-theory

I have seen another question like this in this page, and I know the solution. However, I wanted to ask, does this condition $d(u)+d(v) \geq n-1$  imply that every vertex must have degree at least $n/2$? If not, some vertex would have degree smaller than $n/2$ and I think that should not be possible?

Comment: Consider the complete graph $K_3$ with an extra vertex $v$ and with an edge from $v$ to only one vertex of $K_3$.  The degree-sum inequality is satisfied, but $v$ has degree $1<2=n/2$ ($n=4$ in this example).  However, at most one vertex of any graph $G$ on $n$ vertices satisfying the degree-sum inequality can have degree less than $\frac{n-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the condition is that for every pair $u,v$ of *distinct* vertices we have $d(u)+d(v)\geq n-1$, then no, we can have one vertex of very low degree.

For example, take a complete graph on $n-1$ vertices and add another vertex adjacent to one of the others. In this graph $n-2$ vertices have degree $n-2$, one has degree $n-1$ and one has degree $1$, so any pair of distinct vertices has total degree at least $n-2+1=n-1$.

We can deduce that all but one of the vertices have degree at least $\frac{n-1}2$ (but not necessarily $\frac n2$ since $n$ might be odd).

Answer (score 0):

Hint to solve the original problem: take two vertices that are not neighbors, and show that they must have at least one neighbor in common.

Comment: This is not a hint of the OP's question, though.

Comment: @Batominovski I realised that after I posted it. Then I edited to make it clear. I intend to keep it up, though, since it may help the OP anyways, and for posterity's sake.

Comment: I personally have no problem with your answer.  There are some users who will vote down or even delete your answer, if you do not directly respond to the question, regardless of how useful your answer may be.  (And these users don't care even when you clarify why your answer is useful.)